# discord.py getting all text channels under a certain category - in python

Tags: discord.py

i have seen the following snipped from @Patrick Haugh:

```
from discord import CategoryChannel

@bot.command()
async def comm(ctx, *, category: CategoryChannel):
    channels = category.channels
    print(channels)
```

However I want to be able to get all channels in a category without having to send a message to the bot, e.g. something along those lines:

```
def get_channels(category):
   channels = all_channels_in_category
   return channels
```

I want to get the channels directly in the python code.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

It is mostly the same as in your command

```py
def get_channels(category):
   channels = category.channels
   return channels
```